# Only lower half of the Action Bar is showing (and it is behind the status bar)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

For some reason only the lower half of the `ActionBar` is being displayed, and the half that is showing is behind the status bar. Why could this happen?
This happens only in the `DrawerActivity`.

It must be something with the newer versions of Android because I noticed the bug in Android 5.0.2 and 6.0. In Android 4.4.4 there is no issue.

I'm extendig my `Activity` from the `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` and implementing some fragments in it.

This is my app configuration:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mypackage.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
}
```

The layout for the `DrawerActivity`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include 
        layout="@layout/app_bar_drawer" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView 
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" 
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_drawer" 
        app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

styles.xml :

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

`onCreate` method of `DrawerActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Setting floating button
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //Setting up default fragment.
    Fragment fragment = HomeFragment.newInstance(null, null);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment);
    ft.commit();

}
```

Here's a screenshot for better understanding:

[image: Action bar behind the status bar]

Thank you!

Comment: Please post the layout for your `DrawerActivity`.

Comment: Please, post also styles.xml (especially for v21) and, probably, Activity's code. So far - I can recommend to create an app from the template "Navigation Drawer Activity" and compare it with your code.

Comment: So far - it looks just fine. Have you try the compile standard "Navigation Drawer Activity" app? Does it work as expected? (if not - I'd suggest to update buildToolsVersion to the latest version(23.1.2). if yes - then it's a shortcut to find the issue).

Comment: thanks for your help I will try that and figure out the issue

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your oncreate

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    //then set status bar color or any thing else
}
```